# Creating an AngularJS filter in order to replace double quotes with single quotes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to replace double quotes with single quotes in a filter like this:

INPUT:
This is what I want to "happen" in the filter

OUTPUT:
This is what I want to 'happen' in the filter

This was my attempt:

```
.filter('quoteSingle', function() {
    return function(text) {
      return text.replace("&quot", '&apos');
    };
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this `text.replace(/"/g, "'" )`